# JSP and Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have some code. It works in JSp but not in Java servlet. I am pasting my code here. Can u plz state the mistake in servlet file?

**JSP:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String rollno=null;
String category=null;
rollno=request.getParameter("rollno");
category=request.getParameter("category");
out.println(rollno+"\n"+category+"\n");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java Servlet :-**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;


import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class a extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            String rollno=null;
        String category=null;
        rollno=request.getParameter("rollno");
        category=request.getParameter("category");
        out.println(rollno+"\n"+category+"\n");
    }
     }
```

Comment: What does _It works in JSp but not in Java servlet_ mean?

Comment: The only difference I can see is the HTML head and other tags (which the servlet does not produce). And of course, the JSP responds to not only POST.

Comment: scriplets it is not good idea

Comment: In future questions, tell about the error instead of ignoring it. Errors contain the answer to your problem. You would have gotten a "HTTP 405 method not allowed" error which is already the whole answer at its own (which just need to be translated to layman's terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use doGet method not doPost

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

Comment: +1 because this may actually be the answer to this completely unclear question.